# Wildcard MX domain record and Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, dns

I am a Google Apps user and I want to be able to **catch all emails sent to   * @*.domain.com**

Google apps does offer a feature called "catch-all email account" that intercepts non-existing addresses on a domain... But I need it to work for subdomains as well. Will it work if I add a wildcard MX record like "*.domain.com" that will also point to Google's servers?

Comment: I actually tried this, but with no luck. I've added a wildcard MX record, sent an email to "info@test.mydomain.com" but Google responded with "550 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist". I even have a catch-all account, but no luck :(( Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [webmasters.se] and [sf].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do, you can't use wildcards for sub-domains.

You will have to set up a catch all account for each sub-domain.

Comment: Thanks... Sad... Maybe any other "non-google" way to make this happen?